# No driver is generated after building a sample project in visual studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019, windows-driver

I'm trying to build [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver) sample which is a simple hello world driver. The problem is that the solution is successfully built but no output is generated in the output directory.

The configuration is set on `Release` and the platform is x64. I've also defined `_X86_` in preprocessing definitions. `MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest)` and also `MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 Spectre-mitigated libs (Latest)` are installed as well. Spectre Mitigation (`/Qspectre`) is also enabled.

Here are the output logs:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: practice, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Device.c
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\km\wdm.h(18619,1): warning C4391: 'ULONG __readcr3(void)': incorrect return type for intrinsic function, expected 'unsigned __int64'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\km\wdm.h(18638,1): warning C4391: 'UINT32 __readeflags(void)': incorrect return type for intrinsic function, expected 'unsigned __int64'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\km\wdm.h(24895,9): warning C4163: '_InterlockedAddLargeStatistic': not available as an intrinsic function
1>Done building project "practice.vcxproj".
```